# How to debug command line input in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have this simple program:

```
process.stdin.once("data", function (data) {
    console.log("You said your name is " + data);
    process.stdin.pause();
});
console.log("What is your name?");
process.stdin.resume();
```

Now I put a breakpoint inside a callback:

[image]

And run the program, the `console` tab is open:

[image]

But whatever I type into the terminal in this `console` tab doesn't trigger a breakpoint. It seems that this `console` tab is not a terminal used to accept input from a user.

Comment: I googled how to turn off this stupid feature for 30 minutes....thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While debugging, make sure that "Use Console Input" toggle button on console's toolbar is NOT pressed - when it's pressed, console is in 'live' mode, all entered expressions are evaluated, so stdin is disabled.

[image]

Comment: yes, that was it, thanks a lot! You're saying _all entered expressions are evaluated_ - what scope is used? Because, for example, the function `require` is not available, in this env, but `encodeURI` is available

Comment: it's current execution scope - same as used when evaluating expressions in debugger

Comment: I don't understand why global `require` is not available. Or is it an execution context of a standalone v8 engine without app specific functions?

Comment: hm, I created [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186139/what-is-the-console-tab-evaluation-environment) to debug it. Can you please take a look?