# What is the `console` tab evaluation environment

Tags: webstorm

Suppose I a script in a debugging mode and `console` tab is open and the following is output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.2\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=50811 --expose_debug_as=v8debug C:\Users\maksym.koretskyi\Desktop\nodejs\http.js bo----3
Debugger listening on [::]:50811
```

Then I start typing in expressions, like `console.log(3)`, but nothing is outputted:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

[image]

i'd suggest creating support ticket

Comment: what is your version?

Comment: it's 2016.3.2. But, to me, it works just in the same way in 2016.2.4. My Node.js version is 6.9.1

Comment: When I restarted, `console.log(4)` outputted. But `‌‌var a = require.resolve('./f')` produces `‌ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Does it work for you? Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: may be, application execution has already been completed? add a breakpoint and, once it's hit, try evaluating `require.resolve('./f')` - what is the result?

Comment: thanks, yes, it seems that application has already been completed. Can you add this as an answer? I have a question though, why the studio doesn't show that application is exited and keeps console active/